# Serialize Sealed class within a data class using Gson in kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, gson, json-deserialization, sealed-class

I have created a sealed class for the json field `Value` under `CustomAttribute` data class. This field can return `String` or `Array of Strings`.

How can we deserialize this sealed class from json?

```
data class CustomAttribute (
     val attributeCode: String,
     val value: Value 
)

sealed class Value {
      class StringArrayValue(val value: List<String>) : Value()
      class StringValue(val value: String)            : Value()
}
```

Comment: Can i ask why do you need a value parameter that can be or a list or a single string value? I asked because im curios not to critizied, btw can this help or you already look at it? 
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/103

Comment: @Dak28 It was required as the API can return any of these values at a time. Thanks for the link but I still not able to solve this, can you please help in this..

Answer (score 4):

I created a `TypeAdapterFactory` implementation specifically to support sealed classes and their subtypes. This works similarly to the `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` (and I used it as a guide to write my class), but will specifically only support sealed types, and will deserialize using object instances of objects with a sealed class supertype (`RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` will create a new instance of object types, which breaks equality checks when a single instance is the expectation).

```
private class SealedTypeAdapterFactory<T : Any> private constructor(
    private val baseType: KClass<T>,
    private val typeFieldName: String
) : TypeAdapterFactory {

    private val subclasses = baseType.sealedSubclasses
    private val nameToSubclass = subclasses.associateBy { it.simpleName!! }

    init {
        if (!baseType.isSealed) throw IllegalArgumentException("$baseType is not a sealed class")
    }

    override fun <R : Any> create(gson: Gson, type: TypeToken<R>?): TypeAdapter<R>? {
        if (type == null || subclasses.isEmpty() || subclasses.none { type.rawType.isAssignableFrom(it.java) }) return null

        val elementTypeAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonElement::class.java)
        val subclassToDelegate: Map<KClass<*>, TypeAdapter<*>> = subclasses.associateWith {
            gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, TypeToken.get(it.java))
        }
        return object : TypeAdapter<R>() {
            override fun write(writer: JsonWriter, value: R) {
                val srcType = value::class
                val label = srcType.simpleName!!
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") val delegate = subclassToDelegate[srcType] as TypeAdapter<R>
                val jsonObject = delegate.toJsonTree(value).asJsonObject

                if (jsonObject.has(typeFieldName)) {
                    throw JsonParseException("cannot serialize $label because it already defines a field named $typeFieldName")
                }
                val clone = JsonObject()
                clone.add(typeFieldName, JsonPrimitive(label))
                jsonObject.entrySet().forEach {
                    clone.add(it.key, it.value)
                }
                elementTypeAdapter.write(writer, clone)
            }

            override fun read(reader: JsonReader): R {
                val element = elementTypeAdapter.read(reader)
                val labelElement = element.asJsonObject.remove(typeFieldName) ?: throw JsonParseException(
                    "cannot deserialize $baseType because it does not define a field named $typeFieldName"
                )
                val name = labelElement.asString
                val subclass = nameToSubclass[name] ?: throw JsonParseException("cannot find $name subclass of $baseType")
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                return (subclass.objectInstance as? R) ?: (subclassToDelegate[subclass]!!.fromJsonTree(element) as R)
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun <T : Any> of(clz: KClass<T>) = SealedTypeAdapterFactory(clz, "type")
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(SealedTypeAdapterFactory.of(Value::class)).create()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is just to serialize, the following code will do it. If you are stuck with an older Gson version and want to deserialize too, Jasons SealedTypeAdapterFactory works well.

```
private val serializer = JsonSerializer<MySuperclass> { src, _, context ->
   context!!.serialize(src)
      .also { it.asJsonObject.addProperty("type", src?.javaClass?.simpleName) }


val GSON: Gson = GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(MySuperclass::class.java, serializer)
    .create()
```

Answer (score -4):

I have successfully serialized and de-serialized a sealed class in the past, with a disclaimer of using Jackson, not Gson as my serialization engine.

My sealed class has been defined as:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, visible = true)
sealed class FlexibleResponseModel
    class SnapshotResponse(val collection: List<EntityModel>): FlexibleResponseModel()
    class DifferentialResponse(val collection: List<EntityModel>): FlexibleResponseModel()
    class EventDrivenResponse(val collection: List<EntityEventModel>): FlexibleResponseModel()
    class ErrorResponse(val error: String): FlexibleResponseModel()
```

With the annotations used, it required no further configuration for the Jackson instance to properly serialize and de-serialize instances of this sealed class granted that both sides of the communication possessed a uniform definition of the sealed class.

While I recognise that `JsonTypeInfo` is a Jackson-specific annotation, perhaps you might consider switching over from Gson if this feature is a must - or you might be able to find an equivalent configuration for Gson which would also include the class identifier in your serialized data.

Comment: I am currently using Gson in the application so at this stage cannot change to Jackson. I wiill try to find its equivalent in gson.

Comment: @AkashBisariya and did you find it?

Comment: No,i just made it nullable and check at runtime the type of value @noloman